# Duplicates: posing the same question inside and outside a framework

Tags: discussion

I just asked "can javascript do x-y-z?". The question was marked as a duplicate of "can jquery do x-y-z?". The jquery question did indeed have upvoted answers pointing out the limitations of javascript on the whole.

Was my second question a duplicate because the answer already existed on SO, or not because the answer existed filed under a framework I'm not using?

Answer (score 8):

I’ve marked the other two questions as a duplicate of yours, because you got *two* fresh, new, correct answers that aren’t “no, that’s impossible” – and they apply everywhere! Congratulations on the excellent question.

And as for framework versus non-framework questions in general for JavaScript, there’s usually a large similarity between the two; sometimes, the original question can be edited to make it widely applicable. Give that a try if the answers are worth it.

Answer (score 3):

The 'close as a duplicate of' phrase used to have the terminology 'exact', meaning all elements had to fit. It also meant we had dozens of meta posts complaining that posts that really were duplicates weren't exact duplicates.

[In your case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22029033/can-javascript-tell-the-difference-between-left-and-right-shift-key), the answer to the JQuery question doesn't really answer your question, and yours should not be marked as a duplicate.

The other questions and answers are not well written enough to serve as a canonical source, the questions and the accepted answers would have to be edited to be useful to apply directly to your question.

Comment: How would you assess it if the question was different but the accepted answer still applicable - I would argue in this case the answer **is** applicable (because of how the answer is formulated) albeit low quality and outdated. Would you link just the answer instead? In a comment? Would you keep the close vote?